# How can I get sum of rows of a table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a table what show counts. I designed with ExtJS what my table. I can get summary of my table columns. I want to get summary of rows. How can I do it with Javascript on ExtJs ?

my table:
[image: my table]

My summary renderer what get sum of each column:

```
summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data, metaData) { return '<span style=color:#00B2EE;font-weight:bold;text-align: center;>' +val+'</span>'} ;
```

I want to get sum of my rows like this :

[image: example]

I did like below but it couldn't run. The output of below code blocks are in below screenshot. How can I improve my code blocks ?

```
var tutar =0;
var record = this.up('RadyolojiSorgulamaForm').down("#grdHizmetSayilari").getStore().data.items;
if(record.length>0){
    for(var i = 0;i<record.length;i++){
        toplam =tutar+record[i].data.toplam;
```

[image: above code blocks's output]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [calculate](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-calculate) feature to compute a new [field](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html) in the [store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html).

```
{
    name: 'summary',
    calculate: function (data) {
        let summary = 0;

        Ext.Object.eachValue(data, function (value) {
            if(Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                summary += value;
            }
        });

        return summary;
    }
}
```

You can just use this new computed field as a new column in your [grid](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html).

Here is a working example: [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ma4)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But my Sencha version is old version (I guess) so the calculate feature couldn't run.  I edited the question. Can you help about given edited question ? @DerKorb

Comment: You can test your version using my fiddle. If calculate doesn't work you can try "convert"

Answer (score -1):

Give the dynamically created tablename and rowId in following snippet, should work.

```
document.getElementById('tablename').rows[rowId].cells.length
```

Comment: How can I implement it ? I tried it but can not run. @LCWworker

Comment: Give the dynamically created table an id then put the id you gave instead of youtalbename and it will mostly work.